# Looking for a Function With Certain Characteristics

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a function such that:

$$f(3)=8,$$

$$f'(3)=5,$$

and $\lim_{x \to 3} f '(x)$ does NOT exist.

Comment: Maybe find a function $g$ such that $g'(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} g'(x)$ does not exist. Once you find such a $g$, constructing an $f$ with the listed properties should not be difficult.

Comment: Do you need to clarify whether $x \to 3 - 0$ or  $x \to 3 + 0$?

Answer (score 5):

The classical example of a function that is continuous and differentiable everywhere, but where the derivative fails to be continuous is
$$
g(x) = \cases{x^2\sin(1/x^2)& if $x \neq 0$\\0 & if $x = 0$}
$$
The derivative of $g$ as $x$ approaches $0$ fluctuates wildly, so the limit does not exist. However, the derivative at $0$ is $0$, since $g(x)$ is squeezed between $x^2$ and $-x^2$.

We just need to change it up a bit to make a function $f$ that fits your criteria. First of all, we're interested in $x = 3$, not $x = 0$, so we use $g(x-3)$. Second, we want $f(3) = 8$, so we change our function to $g(x-3) + 8$. Lastly, we want $f'(3) = 5$, so we add $5x - 15$ (the $-15$ is to not ruin $f(3) = 8$). We end up with
$$
f(x) = g(x-3) + 5x - 7
$$